# Urban Airship iOS Badges not resetting to 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

The tutorial ["Here"](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios_features.html#badges) is a little confusing so wondering if anyone has already implemented this. The app is using "UA's autobadge" feature and the badge number is cleared when the app is open, however it is not reset to 0. So, when a new notification arrives, it forever increments the badge number.

The code I have in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is:

```
UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];
[config setAutomaticSetupEnabled:NO];
[[UAPush shared] setNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
[[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotifications];
[UAirship takeOff:config];
[[UAPush shared] setAutobadgeEnabled:YES];
[[UAPush shared] resetBadge];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Is there something trivial I am doing wrong? Has anybody got this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have this and it clears the badge once messages are read:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
// Set the application's badge to the number of unread messages
if ([UAInbox shared].messageList.unreadCount >= 0) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UAInbox shared].messageList.unreadCount];
}}
```